# React Native Text Element- Using an identically named import

Tags: react-native

I have these imports at the top of my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native'
import { LineChart, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'
import * as shape from 'd3-shape'
import { Circle, G, Line, Rect, Text } from 'react-native-svg'
```

I want to use both the Text node from react-native and the Text node from react-native-svg, can this be done?

The error I'm getting is duplicate declaration Text, and I can see why. But I wish to use them both in my code, in segments like:

```
 <G y={ 50 }>
    <Rect
        height={ 40 }
        width={ 75 }
        stroke={ 'grey' }
        fill={ 'white' }
        ry={ 10 }
        rx={ 10 }
    />
    <Text
        x={ 75 / 2 }
        dy={ 20 }
        alignmentBaseline={ 'middle' }
        textAnchor={ 'middle' }
        stroke={ 'rgb(134, 65, 244)' }
    >
        { `${data[5]}ºC` }
    </Text>
</G>
```

and further down in my code:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{height: '100%', justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>back</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rename your import with what you want using `as <MyName>` notation

`import { Circle, G, Line, Rect, Text as TextSvg } from 'react-native-svg'` should work.

And then use `<TextSvg />`